# Center RadioButtonList inside a panel

Tags: asp.net, center, radiobuttonlist, listitem

I cannot seem to be able to center my RadioButtonList inside a panel. It always seems to e left justified. No matter what I try.

My current code is:

```
<asp:panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="style8" Height="228px" 
  width="456px">
  <br /> 
         <p style ="text-align:center">
              <asp:Label ID+"Label2" runat="server" Text="Blah">
              </asp:Label>
        </p>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="AlertClients" runat="Server" TextAlign="Right" 
       style="list-style=center">
              <asp:ListItem> Option 1</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem> Option 2</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem> Option 3</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put this tag in your Radio Button List control: align="center"

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="AlertClients" runat="Server" TextAlign="Right" Style="list-style=center" align="center">
 <asp:ListItem> Option 1</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem> Option 2</asp:ListItem>
 <asp:ListItem> Option 3</asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my view use div instead of panel. But as in panel you can also try with giving

```
style="margin:auto;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I bet you need to edit the style8 referenced by the panel  and add **tex-align: center;**

```
<style>
  .style8
      {
        text-align:center;
      }
 </style>
```